# FindMinimum[]'s objective function evaluation works with EvaluationMonitor but not StepMonitor

Tags: mathematical-optimization, syntax

I'm trying to monitor the progress of FindMinimum[] using StepMonitor.  I'd specifically like to have the code print out the value of the objective function and the variable values. For example,

```
FindMinimum[{objF = objFunc[x, y], x >0, y>0}, {{x, 1}, {y, 1}},
  StepMonitor:> {Print[{objF, x, y}]}
]
```

where I've been careful to restrict calculation of `objFunc[]` to only the cases where it has numerical values for x and y. That is,

```
 objF[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := Module[{}, ....]
```

When I try running the `FindMinimum[]` above, my output looks like this.

```
 {objFunc[x, y], 0.235, 1.875}
 {objFunc[x, y], 0.244, 1.654}
```

I've tried using

- `StepMonitor:> {Print[{Evaluate[objF], x, y}]}`
- `StepMonitor:> {Print[{objF/.{x->x, y->y}, x, y}]}`
- `StepMonitor:> {Print[{objF/.{Hold[x]->x, Hold[y]->y}, x, y}]}`

But none of them give the desired results.

Confusingly, to me anyway, EvaluationMonitor behaves the way I expect. That is,

```
EvaluationMonitor:> {Print[{objF, x, y}]}
```

Produces,

```
{33.456, 1.000, 1.000}
{32.456, 0.235, 1.875}
{31.555, 0.244, 1.654}
```

How do I solve this issue?

ps. Perhaps these problems would be solved using Reap[] and Sow[], but I'd like to monitor the progress of the optimization in real time, not after the fact.

Answer (score 2):

It is because `FindMinimum` has the attribute `HoldAll` and you need to inject the expression `objFunc[x, y]` or `objF[x, y]` (it appears both ways in the OP currently) into the `StepMonitor` code.  Injection can be accomplished with [`With`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/With.html).  What appears to happen is this:

- At each step, any appearances of `x` and `y` in the literal code `{objF, x, y}` passed to `StepMonitor` are replaced by their numeric values at the current step.
- The resulting expression is evaluated. At this point the symbol `objF` evaluates to `objFunc[x, y]`, which appears as is when printed, since `objFunc` does not evaluate on symbolic input.

I could show how on a minimal working example, but there isn't one.